# Is there any way to make an Access button hyperlink based off of a table record?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a button with a hyperlink to an Internet address.

Ideally, I'd like the button to link to whatever address is in a link lookup table.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks,
Catherine

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use [DLookUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa159044%28v=office.10%29.aspx) and [FollowHyperlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221236%28office.11%29.aspx):

```
FollowHyperlink DlookUp("MyLink","MyLinktable","OptionalCriteria")
```